# Loading PetaBytes of data at scale

Tags: performance, hadoop, apache-spark, hpcc, bigdata

I need to load petabytes of text data into a storage (RAM/SSD) within a second.

Below are some of the question to solve the above problem.

1)  Is it practically/theoretically possible to load petabytes of data in a second?
2) What will be the best design approach in order to achive fast loading of petabyte scale data in sub seconds.
3) Any benchmark approach available?.

I am okay to implement with any kind of technologies like Hadoop, spark, HPCC etc...

Comment: I don't see why not. Given enough time and money, sure. You'll probably need 1000-2000 servers per PB though to achieve this scale

Answer (score 5):

"petabytes .... within a second". seriously? Please check [wikipedia Petabyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petabyte): it is 1.000.000 GB!

Also check [wikipedia Memory bandwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_bandwidth). Even the fastest RAM cannot handle more than a few 10 GB / s (in practice this is far lower).

Just curious: what is your use-case?

Comment: I got it, I am not looking only for RAM based solution even it can be SSD.

Comment: My use case is on research project on nuclear physics like CERN.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not technically possible at this time. Not even RAM memory is fast enough (not to mention the obvious capacity constraints). The fastest SSD (M.2 drives) you can get write speed around 1.2GB/s and with raid 0, you might achieve speeds just around 3GB/s at most. There are also economical constraints, as those drives by themselves are quite expensive. 
 So to answer your question, those speeds are technically impossible at current time.

Answer (score 0):

From HPCC perspective...

**Thor** is designed to load data and support multiple servers. However the biggest cluster I heard about is about 4000 servers. Thor is designed to load a lot of data over long time (even a week).

In the other hand **Roxie** is designed to serve data quickly but is not what you are asking for...nor it could serve Petabytes under a second.